# WndProc hook does not receive WM_COMMAND from menus

Tags: c++, winapi

For tracking user activity, I am using a Windows Hook for the main application thread, and monitor (among others) WM_COMMAND messages.

I receive them as expected from dialog buttons, toolbar buttons, accelerators and popup menus, but I do NOT receive them from the main menu.

Strangely enough, Spy++ does show the main window receiving them. What could be wrong?

Installing the hook:

```
currentHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, 
                               HookProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

HookProc, minimalistic:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
   CWPSTRUCT cwp = *(CWPSTRUCT *)lp;
   if (cwp.message == WM_COMMAND)
   {
      ATLTRACE("[hook!] WM_COMMAND id=%d\n", LOWORD(cwp.wParam));
   }
   return CallNextHookEx(currentHook, nCode, wp, lp);
}
```

(The actual code is more complex, and needs to check for reentrancy etc., but I've remvoed it for this test)

Any ideas?

[Edit] the main window I test is an MFC application, but the instrumentation code does not use any MFC.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but is it possible to get the existing WNDPROC using GetWindowLong and GWL_WNDPROC, setting the new WNDPROC to your own custom one with SetWindowLong, and in your new WNDPROC call the old one using CallWindowProc? This way you'll get absolutely all window messages and not have to worry about hooks. I don't know if it's possible though, but it's how I would have originally attempted to approach the issue.

Comment: @dreamlax: I've already tried sublassing, this works fine. Still, I'd have to add one line to the Create/OnInitDialog of each "relevant" window which - at this point - I still want to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu commands are posted, not sent (yes, the documentation is rather unclear on this - but Spy++ tells the truth). And `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hooks only catch sent messages.

You should be able to use a [`WH_GETMESSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644981.aspx) hook to intercept posted messages. You'll *need* both if you want to handle both forms of `WM_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to track WM_MENUCOMMAND?

Comment: requires the MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS set for the menu - but I want to avoid code/ressource changes in the project to instrument. Also, I'd have to figure out which WM_MENUCOMMAND messages are not followed by a WM__COMMAND message - sounds ugly